# Skype integration

Tags: api, skype

Does the Skype api support integration with third party apps where by Skype calls can be made from external apps or thorough your address book .Received wouldn't be a problem as it would not show in the main screen when a call comes through.

Answer (score 1):

The Skype Web API supports starting calls and receiving calls from your web application: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/ptaudiooutgoing

The Skype for Business App SDK supports joining Skype meetings with audio, video, and chat from a mobile Android or iOS application: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/apioverview.  Note that the calls supported in this case are not PSTN and not peer-to-peer. They are only for joining meetings.

For Windows apps on Windows 7,8, and 10 computers, as long as the Skype for Business client is installed on the computer, you can enable your app to make peer-to-peer audio calls through the Lync 2013 API. You can find more information about this API in the MSDN library under  "Lync 2013 SDK Documentation". The app user must have SfB credentials for either Skype for Business Online or an organization's on premise Skype for Business server.